# What's The Different between data class and inline class in kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm, jetbrains-ide

In The **kotlin 1.5.0** we have seen the `inline class` with `value` declaration, but that seems similar to `data class` except for we can only make one variable in `inline class` and in `data class` we can make more.

But I'm still wondering What the idea about `inline class`? or what we can do in `inline class` and in `data class` can't ?

Comment: [inline-classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html), [data-classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html)

Answer (score 3):

Inline class is all about wrapping a type in a new class. It is more like type aliases but it also gives us type safety which type aliases don't. Inline classes are replaced with the underlying datatype in java code.

This article gives really good insight about inline classes and some gotchas: [Inline Classes and Autoboxing in Kotlin](https://typealias.com/guides/inline-classes-and-autoboxing/)

On the other hand, if the class is designed to only hold certain data then data class might be a good option,

```
data class User(val name: String, val followersCount: Int){}
```

Then the class will automatically provide some default methods for us.

```
val user = User("Youn", 5000)

// a default toString() method is implemented
println(user) // User(name=Youn, followersCount=5000)

// this is known as destructuring
// provided by the default componentN() function
val (name, followersCount) = User("Tivoli", 5)

// type of *name* is inferred to *String* and *followersCount* to *Int*
// name = Tivoli, followersCount = 5
```

Moreover, default implementations of `equals()` and `copy()` are also provided in data class. Check out more: [Data Class Kotlinlang docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html)